# BeautifulSoup with python unable to get value of a h2 tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get this value from this [web page](http://larepublica.pe/) from the "Economia" section:

[image]

I want to get all those titles. This is my current code:

```
html = client.get("http://larepublica.pe/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

# Obtener la noticia de portada principal
economyNews = ""
for div in soup.findAll('h2', attrs={'class':'ItemSection_itemSection__title__PleA9'}):
    n = div.text
    economyNews += n+"\\n"

print(economyNews )
```

I have tested many ways to get this, but seems that the webpage is locking this.
Any idea to fix this problem guys I will appreciate it. Thanks so much.

Comment: If it's generated by Javascript, you'll need a solution like Selenium that can execute the Javascript. When scraping static content, always look in the Sources tab, not Elements. If you're doing static-content scraping, you can only see what's in the "Sources" tab in your code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's not dynamically generated.

Comment: It looks like the website is detecting whether the request comes from a browser or a web scraper, and blocking scrapers.

Comment: @Barmar yes that's could be possible, I will wait if someone has a idea or I will need to avoid it and start with another webpage.

Comment: Using Selenium should work around this, since it uses a web browser.

Comment: I will test it, works with python through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://larepublica.pe/"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")


for h2 in soup.select("div:has(*:-soup-contains(Economía)) + div h2"):
    print(h2.text)
```

Prints:

```
Banco Mundial: tasas de interés se mantendrán altas por más tiempo
Precio del dólar cierra al alza y se ubica en S/3,831 este miércoles 11 de octubre
Retiro AFP: ¿cuándo fue la última vez que se autorizó la liberación de fondos y cuánto se devolvió?
Debate sobre RETIRO AFP 2023: SBS y Congreso deliberaron sobre posible medida
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much for your contribution dear, this avoided to use Selenium.. keep it up!.

Comment: Hi bro, could you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284406/beautifulsoup-with-python-unable-to-get-value-of-a-span-tag thanks.