# BeautifulSoup with python unable to get value of a span tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the value from the main titular news from this [web page](https://elperuano.pe/)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
news = ""
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0"
}

url = "https://elperuano.pe/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')


#Obtener noticia principal
for div in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class':'card-title fz18 lh30 fw500 width100'}):
    print(div.text)
```

This is the unique span tag with has that class name "card-title fz18 lh30 fw500 width100". I don't know why this doesn't work.
However if try to get the value of the date of the newspaper this works:

```
for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'lh18'}):
    n = div.text.rstrip("\n\n")
```

I have tested many ways to get this, but seems that the webpage is locking this. Any idea to fix this problem guys I will appreciate it. Thanks so much.

Comment: _I don't know why this doesn't work_ Saying that something "doesn't work" is a poor description of the problem.  If you're getting an error, post it.  If you're getting empty/unwanted results, post them and show the results you wanted instead.

Comment: I'm guessing the reason is that the page uses javascript to dynamically create its contents, and `requests` can't process javascript.

Comment: @JohnGordon ok thanks. I have a question, do you think that by using selenium could fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the page dynamically loads news. You need to use **_GetPortadaPrincipal** and **_GetNoticiasDestacadas** methods to get the news you need

```
import requests

principal_news = requests.get('https://elperuano.pe/Portal/_GetPortadaPrincipal').json()
print('Title:', principal_news['vchTitulo'].strip())
print('Description:', principal_news['vchDescripcion'].strip())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Title: Presidenta Dina Boluarte invita a empresarios alemanes a invertir en el país
Description: La presidenta de la República, Dina Boluarte, se reunió en Alemania con un grupo de empresarios y directivos de ese país, a quienes invitó a invertir en el Perú.
```

Or you can get recommended news like that:

```
import requests

recommended_news = requests.get('https://elperuano.pe/Portal/_GetNoticiasDestacadas').json()
for news in recommended_news:
    print('Title:', news['vchTitulo'].strip())
    print('Description:', news['vchDescripcion'].strip())
    print('*' * 10)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Title: Presidenta Dina Boluarte resalta lazos entre Perú y Alemania
Description: La presidenta de la República, Dina Boluarte, destacó los lazos entre Perú y Alemania, y reiteró su invitación a los inversionistas del país europeo, resaltando las fortalezas económicas peruanas.
**********
Title: Cancillería: avión presidencial parte este viernes a Israel para evacuar a connacionales
Description: El Ministerio de Relaciones Exteriores informó que se hará uso del avión presidencial para evacuar de Israel a nuestros connacionales que aún permanecen en dicho país.
**********
Title: Premier Otárola: "no escatimaremos esfuerzos para repatriar a los peruanos en Israel"
Description: El presidente del Consejo de Ministros, Alberto Otárola, sostuvo que el Gobierno ha realizado el empadronamiento de los peruanos que están varados en Israel y está en condiciones de comunicar serán repatriados en el avión presidencial, protegiendo su vida e integridad
**********
Title: Jefe del Gabinete se reunió con autoridades del Callao y el Cusco
Description: El jefe del Gabinete Ministerial, Alberto Otárola, se reunió con los autoridades municipales de la Mancomunidad Municipal del Callao, y de la provincia cusqueña de Chumbivilcas, con quienes coordinó las necesidades de sus respectivas jurisdicciones para canalizarlas.
**********
Title: Presidenta Boluarte despacha con Ministros a través de medios tecnológicos
Description: La presidenta Dina Boluarte sostuvo una reunión con ministros de Estado a través de los medios tecnológicos, con la finalidad de seguir atendiendo el Despacho Presidencial, en un alto de sus actividades oficiales en Alemania.
**********
Title: Jefa del Estado sostiene encuentro con alcalde de Stuttgart en Alemania
Description: La presidenta Dina Boluarte se reunió con el alcalde de Stuttgart, Alemania, Frank Nopper, dando inicio a sus actividades oficiales en ese país.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is another way of get the news.

Answer (score 1):

Hei, I tried getting the full page from beautifulsoup and figured out I'm getting a skeleton version of the page, as you can see in the image. I copied all the headers from my browser and it was still the same, so I'm guessing it's 'cause there is some functionality missing from the scrapper: no cookies, no javascript, different screen size, etc. You can try adding some of these to beautifulsoup. Or use a headless browser.

[image: beautifulsoup result]

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because the page content is dynamically loaded from their API. Meaning that when you access the site initially with bs4, the content is not there yet, therefore the div.text returns empty.

If you check the network log from your browser's developer tools, you can examine which endpoints the data had been fetched from :

[image: Data]

You can either scrape the site with libraries like selenium in which you can scrape the page with contents are loaded or get the data you need from their API.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks